# What's the best way to minify the ASP.NET generated Javascript?

Tags: javascript, optimization, asp.net-3.5, minify, webresource.axd

What's the best way to minify the ASP.NET generated Javascript, such as the ones served by webresource.axd, in ASP.NET 3.5 at runtime?  I tried using the [MbCompression](http://mbcompression.codeplex.com/) module but it's not working with those resources.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to minify the ASP.NET AJAX JavaScript, ensure that you've updated the compilation section of your web.config to turn off Debug mode:

```
<compilation debug="false">
```

This will ensure that the ScriptResource files are minified, however unless you've supplied minified versions of your JS files, these won't be touched.

Comment: Any references to this process?

Comment: Note that this will minify `ScriptResource.axd` only. For some reason, `WebResource.axd` doesn't get minified.

Comment: Could you please look at this and help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198461/combining-multiple-calls-to-scriptresource-axd

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the Ajax Minifier described in [this blog post by ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/15/announcing-microsoft-ajax-library-preview-6-and-the-microsoft-ajax-minifier.aspx)?

It might be just what you are looking for.