# combining multiple calls to ScriptResource.axd

Tags: asp.net, performance, webforms, scriptresource.axd

I am trying to minimize calls to `ScriptResource.axd` but i have failed. Below is the result

[image]

Uaing .Net 4.0, AjaxControlToolkit ver 4.1.60919.0 and ScriptManager is added as

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release">
        <CompositeScript>
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference name="MicrosoftAjax.js"/>
                <asp:ScriptReference name="MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js"/>
                <asp:ScriptReference name="Compat.Timer.Timer.js" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.60919.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e"/>
                <asp:ScriptReference name="Common.Common.js" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.60919.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e"/>
                <asp:ScriptReference name="Animation.Animations.js" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.60919.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e"/>
                <asp:ScriptReference name="ExtenderBase.BaseScripts.js" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.60919.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e"/>
                <asp:ScriptReference name="CollapsiblePanel.CollapsiblePanelBehavior.js" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.60919.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e"/>
            </Scripts>
        </CompositeScript>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

My website was working fine but suddenly customers started complaining that it is slow. I checked the website from client side and found that **every single click takes approx. 10 seconds**, whether it be a DB call or just a simple loop upto 30.

I checked and found that the time between `Application_BeginRequest` and `Application_EndRequest` is less than a second. Then on IE Profiler i came to know that there are various calls to `ScriptResource.axd` and so trying to minify these calls.

Kindly help and let me know what is wrong with these configs.

**Edit**
No success so far in minifying calls to `ScriptResource.axd`. I am pretty much sure that

> every single click takes approx. 10 seconds

because of these multiple calls to `ScriptResource.axd`. If it is something else which is causing this much delay then please guid me towards right direction.

Comment: The image show that all script are come from one link - the `ScriptResource.axd` is optimize (not minifying) but this is not the issue.

Comment: The form submit take the time...., is not what you believe... the time is eating on the submit, see what you do there... form submit, then is says load scripts... what you do there ?

Comment: @Aristos Time between `BeginRequest` and `EndRequest` is less than a second. The Form is a simple aspx form with an `UpdatePanel` having 4 checkbox lists and a gridview with max 2-3 rows.

Comment: remove the UpdatePanel (for tests) to see if and where the delay is.

Comment: @Aristos Strange. While testing your suggested solution i figured it out that the problem is with specific page's file name. I created an exact copy of the page with different file name and it worked as expected. What could be wrong!!!

Comment: Maybe you have felt on session lock, I dont know, take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629600/does-asp-net-web-forms-prevent-a-double-click-submission/11629664#11629664

Comment: @Aristos There was a DropDownList in which, at client side, ~30,000 records were being loaded. This was unexpected. I replaced this DropDownList with a lookup screen and things started working as expected. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a DropDownList in which, at client side, ~30,000 records were being loaded. This was unexpected. I replaced this DropDownList with a lookup screen and things started working as expected.